How do I combine these two 2D ray-casting optimizing algorithms together in Python?
I know what each algorithm does:
DDA: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbSee-XM7WA
"Corner-Joining Algorithm": https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/
But I don't know how to use the DDA algorithm and corner-joining algorithm together.
I tried to implement the corner-joining algorithm (see below) but it doesn't work, I don't know why.
I found a script for the DDA algorithm, it works.
CORNER-JOINING ALGORITHM
##############################################################################

import pygame
import math

#######################################

# Links:
# https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/

#######################################

pygame.init()

X, Y = 800, 800
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
pygame.display.set_caption("2D Ray Tracing")

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

##############################################################################

def drawRays(origin, shapesList):
    # Corner-Joining Algorithm
    #var endpoints     # list of endpoints, sorted by angle
    #var allWalls      # list of all walls the sweep line intersects

    #loop over endpoints:
    #    remember which wall is nearest to the player
    #    ADD walls that BEGIN at this endpoint
    #    DELETE walls that END at this endPoint
    #    figure out which wall is now nearest to the player
    #    if the nearest wall changed:
    #        fill the current triangle and begin a new one

    endPoints = [] # List of endpoints, sorted by angle
    for shape in shapesList:
        for point in shape:
            # Find the angle from player to point (0 degrees = up)
            triangleSides = [abs(origin[0]-point[0]), abs(origin[1]-point[1])]
            radius = math.sqrt(triangleSides[0]**2+triangleSides[1]**2)
            angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(point[1]-origin[1], point[0]-origin[0])-math.atan2((origin[1]-radius)-origin[1], origin[0]-origin[0]))
            if angle < 0: angle += 360
            endPoints.append([point, round(angle, 2)])
    # Bubble sort the endPoints in ascending angles
    for count1 in range(len(endPoints)):
        for count2 in range(0, len(endPoints)-count1-1):
            if endPoints[count2][1] > endPoints[count2+1][1]:
                endPoints[count2], endPoints[count2+1] = endPoints[count2+1], endPoints[count2]

    allWalls = [] # List of walls, sorted by distance
    for shape in shapesList:
        for count in range(len(shape)):
            point1 = shape[count]
            if count+1 > len(shape)-1: point2 = shape[0]
            else: point2 = shape[count+1]
            triangleSides = [abs(point1[0]-point2[0]), abs(point1[1]-point2[1])]
            middleOfWall = [point2[0]-(triangleSides[0]/2), point2[1]-(triangleSides[1]/2)]
            if middleOfWall[1] > Y: middleOfWall[1] -= triangleSides[1]
            if middleOfWall[1] < 0: middleOfWall[1] += triangleSides[1]
            if middleOfWall[0] > X: middleOfWall[0] -= triangleSides[0]
            if middleOfWall[0] < 0: middleOfWall[0] += triangleSides[0]
            # Find distance from player -> middleOfWall
            triangleSides = [abs(origin[0]-middleOfWall[0]), abs(origin[1]-middleOfWall[1])]
            distance = math.sqrt(triangleSides[0]**2+triangleSides[1]**2)
            allWalls.append([point1, middleOfWall, point2, distance])
    # Bubble sort the walls in ascending distance (from player)
    for count1 in range(len(allWalls)):
        for count2 in range(0, len(allWalls)-count1-1):
            if allWalls[count2][3] > allWalls[count2+1][3]:
                allWalls[count2], allWalls[count2+1] = allWalls[count2+1], allWalls[count2]

    walls = allWalls.copy()
    for point, angle in endPoints:
        nearestWall = walls[0]
        # ADD walls that BEGIN at this endpoint
        for data in allWalls:
            if point == data[0]:
                if data != walls:
                    walls.append(data)
                else:
                    break
        # Remove duplicate walls
        noDuplicates = []
        for wall in walls:
            if wall not in noDuplicates:
                noDuplicates.append(wall)
        walls = noDuplicates.copy()
        # DELETE walls that END at this endpoint
        count = 0
        while count < len(walls):
            if point == walls[count][2]:
                del(walls[count])
            count += 1
        # Bubble sort the walls in ascending distance (from player)
        for count1 in range(len(walls)):
            for count2 in range(0, len(walls)-count1-1):
                if walls[count2][3] > walls[count2+1][3]:
                    walls[count2], walls[count2+1] = walls[count2+1], walls[count2]
        if walls[0] != nearestWall: # Fill the current triangle (point1, point2, origin) and begin a new one
            for data in allWalls:
                if point == data[0]:
                    point1 = data[0]
                    point2 = data[2]
                    break
            pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAY, red, [point1, point2, origin])


#######################################

def renderPlayer(playerXY):
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, white, playerXY, radius=10)

#######################################

def renderObjects(shapesList):
    for shape in shapesList:
        pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAY, white, shape, width=5)

##############################################################################

playerXY = [400, 400]

shapesList = [
    [(20, 20), (X-20, 20), (X-20, Y-20), (20, Y-20)], # Outer boundary
    # Obstacles
    [(100, 50), (150, 50), (150, 100), (100, 100)],
]

#######################################

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
    
    heldKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if heldKeys[pygame.K_w] is True:
        playerXY[1] -= 5
    if heldKeys[pygame.K_a] is True:
        playerXY[0] -= 5
    if heldKeys[pygame.K_s] is True:
        playerXY[1] += 5
    if heldKeys[pygame.K_d] is True:
        playerXY[0] += 5
    
    DISPLAY.fill(black)
    drawRays(playerXY, shapesList)
    renderObjects(shapesList)
    renderPlayer(playerXY)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

##############################################################################

DDA ALGORITHM
import pygame
import math

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

def DDA(targetX, targetY):
    
    mouse_cell_x = targetX / cell_size
    mouse_cell_y = targetY / cell_size

    # DDA Algorithm
    ray_start_x, ray_start_y = player_x, player_y
    ray_dir_x = (mouse_cell_x - player_x)
    ray_dir_y = (mouse_cell_y - player_y)
    ray_dir_len = math.sqrt(ray_dir_x ** 2 + ray_dir_y ** 2)
    if ray_dir_len != 0:
        ray_dir_x /= ray_dir_len
        ray_dir_y /= ray_dir_len

    ray_unit_step_x = math.sqrt(1 + (ray_dir_y / ray_dir_x) ** 2) if ray_dir_x != 0 else float('inf')
    ray_unit_step_y = math.sqrt(1 + (ray_dir_x / ray_dir_y) ** 2) if ray_dir_y != 0 else float('inf')

    map_check_x, map_check_y = int(ray_start_x), int(ray_start_y)
    ray_length_x, ray_length_y = 0, 0
    step_x, step_y = 0, 0

    if ray_dir_x < 0:
        step_x = -1
        ray_length_x = (ray_start_x - map_check_x) * ray_unit_step_x
    else:
        step_x = 1
        ray_length_x = (map_check_x + 1 - ray_start_x) * ray_unit_step_x

    if ray_dir_y < 0:
        step_y = -1
        ray_length_y = (ray_start_y - map_check_y) * ray_unit_step_y
    else:
        step_y = 1
        ray_length_y = (map_check_y + 1 - ray_start_y) * ray_unit_step_y

    tile_found = False
    max_distance = 100.0
    distance = 0.0

    while not tile_found and distance < max_distance:
        if ray_length_x < ray_length_y:
            map_check_x += step_x
            distance = ray_length_x
            ray_length_x += ray_unit_step_x
        else:
            map_check_y += step_y
            distance = ray_length_y
            ray_length_y += ray_unit_step_y

        if 0 <= map_check_x < map_width and 0 <= map_check_y < map_height:
            if game_map[map_check_y * map_width + map_check_x] == 1:
                tile_found = True

    intersection_x, intersection_y = None, None
    if tile_found:
        intersection_x = ray_start_x + ray_dir_x * distance
        intersection_y = ray_start_y + ray_dir_y * distance

    # Draw ray
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (player_x * cell_size, player_y * cell_size), (targetX, targetY))
    if tile_found:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (int(intersection_x * cell_size), int(intersection_y * cell_size)), 4)

    return intersection_x * cell_size, intersection_y * cell_size

# Screen dimensions
screen_width, screen_height = 800, 800

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARK_GREY = (64, 64, 64)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Initialize screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("RayCast With DDA Algorithm")

# Initialize map
game_map = [
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
]
# Map dimensions
map_width, map_height = int(math.sqrt(len(game_map))), int(math.sqrt(len(game_map)))
cell_size = int(screen_width/map_width)

# Player
player_x, player_y = (screen_width/2)/cell_size, (screen_height/2)/cell_size
player = pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (int(player_x * cell_size), int(player_y * cell_size)), 4)

# Clock for controlling frame rate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    intersectionsPoints = []
    for point in range(0, 800):
        intersectionsPoints.append(DDA(point, 0)) # Top
        intersectionsPoints.append(DDA(point, 800)) # Bottom
        intersectionsPoints.append(DDA(0, point)) # Left
        intersectionsPoints.append(DDA(800, point)) # Right

    # Drawing
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw map
    for y in range(map_height):
        for x in range(map_width):
            cell = game_map[y * map_width + x]
            rect = pygame.Rect(x * cell_size, y * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
            if cell == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, DARK_GREY, rect, 1)

    # Move player
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    change = 3/cell_size
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player_y -= change
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player_y += change
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x -= change
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player_x += change

    # Draw intersection points
    for point in intersectionsPoints:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (player_x*cell_size, player_y*cell_size), point, 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (point[0], point[1]), 4)

    # Draw player
    player = pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (int(player_x * cell_size), int(player_y * cell_size)), 4)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()

